# get index of first element verifying a condition in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

What is the best way to retrieve the index of the first element verifying a certain condition in a numpy array?

I could do the following

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1])
np.where(x == 2)[0][0]
```

Which would give me the index of the first occurrence of number 2 in the array.

This loops over the entire array, evaluating the condition `x[i] == 2` for all `i` in `range(len(x))` to create a boolean mask which is then passed to `np.where` to retrieve the indices of `True` elements.

Looping over the entire array is not needed, the iteration could stop as soon as the first element verifying the condition is met.

Is there a numpy way to do this without iterating over the entire array?

Comment: using a function with a for loop decreases `Wall time: 2.66 ms` to `Wall time: 1.69 ms` although it's not a native to `numpy` solution